# JS expression not working as part of a string in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could you please help with something?

I’m trying to do the following…

```
import {chosenIpAddress} from './socketEvents.js';

const socket = socketClient(`http:// ${chosenIpAddress} :8081`);
```

…but no matter what I try, it simply ignores my expression and sees it as http://:8081. I’ve tried with plus signs, commas, backticks, quotation marks, shouting, and threatening it, but to no avail.

I can log out the IP address, so I know it’s populated, but as part of the string it just gets ignored and it’s driving me crazy!

Thanks in advance xxx

P.S... I've seen some similar questions, but these do not help with mine, hence the new question.

Update: As requested, this is my export...

```
let chosenIpAddress = "";

function  chosenTank(tank) {
    socket.emit('chosen tank', tank);
    console.log('Tank', tank);
    chosenIpAddress = tank.IpAddress;
}

export {
    chosenIpAddress,
};
```

Comment: What is your `socketEvents.js`?

Comment: It's an intermediary for 'emit' and 'on' events between devices.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're exporting it, right?

Comment: Haha, yes. I can console log it out here, but as part of the string, it just gets ignored.

Comment: That's weird...

Comment: Indeed it is, and at the moment is project critical!

Comment: Just in case anyone else is watching, paste the snippet where you export the variable

Comment: Thanks, updated my question.

Comment: Where is `chosenTank` called?  You're exporting a blank string initially, the function call is probably happening at some other point in time which is why you can log it, but it's interpolated as `""`.

Comment: `chosenTank` is never called, so you export `{ chosenIpAddress: "" }`

Comment: It is being called, I can't paste the whole project as it's very big and has a good separation of concerns so it would be a very long post. Basically, the user is presented with a screen from which they can choose their device from a list of connected devices coming in from the server, and from there, 'chosenTank' called, and the IP address is populated, hence why I can log it out (if they don't choose one, the log is empty).

Comment: I knew it had something to do with export :)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the export, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for anyone who runs into this problem, I worked it out. The answer given is kind of getting there, but not right, I tried that (*and variations of it*), but it/they didn't work.

Basically in my case, the IP address was being set when the application started, so the **chosenIpAddress** would always be an empty string as it's being set before the connections had taken place, no variations of exporting, recalling, or function building would've done the job.

To get around this, I let the initial connection take place with a 'placeholder' socketClient to stop the application from crashing...

```
let socket = socketClient('http://:8081');
```

...and then when ready, I called to repopulate the IP address when the component mounted from the frontend...

*Called from front end when ready...*

```
componentDidMount() {
    frontEndConnected();
}
```

*Add IP address as required...*

```
function frontEndConnected() {
    socket = socketClient(`http://${chosenTankIpAddress}:8081`);
}
```

...which works a charm.

Answer (score 5):

You need to export a function that returns the IP address when called.

The file importing the `chosenIpAddress` has the original value (empty string), but it will never be updated even when `chosenTake` is called. Javascript strings are copied by value, so if you update the original variable, any other references to it *will not be updated*.

- https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

Example of strings copied by value:

```
chosenIpAddress = "";
x = chosenIpAddress; // x is ""
chosenIpAddress = "localhost"; // chosenIpAddress is "localhost", x is still ""
// This same issues applies to imports/exports.
```

So do something like this in your ip address file:

```
let chosenIpAddress = "";

function chosenTank(tank) {
    socket.emit('chosen tank', tank);
    console.log('Tank', tank);
    chosenIpAddress = tank.IpAddress;
}

function getChosenIpAddress() {
    // This can be "" if chosenTank is not called first
    return chosenIpAddress;
}

export {
    getChosenIpAddress,
};
```

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you need to call `chosenTank` before you access the `chosenIpAddress`, or you're going to get an empty string every time.

Further, you'll also need to build the socket string as a function as well, so that it gets the most up-to-date value from `getChosenIpAddress` when it's called:

```
import {getChosenIpAddress} from './socketEvents.js';

function getChosenSocket() {
    return socketClient(`http://${getChosenIpAddress()}:8081`);
}
```

Comment: Still the same. Logs out when selected, but is still ignored as part of the string.

Comment: You need to build the string as a function, too

Comment: No, see my answer for the solution.